# Angular2 Cannot find name 'UISearch'

Tags: jquery, angular

I use external JavaScript library in Angular2. When I start server, I am receiving error in terminal.

> Cannot find name 'UISearch'.
>   [default] Checking finished with 1 errors

My code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    new UISearch( document.getElementById( 'sb-search' ) );
}
```

UISearch has red curve error line. 
I think, that I need append '< any >', but I don't know how. I hope you will help me

Comment: How you imported the JavaScript library into your Angular2 App?

Comment: I installed jquery  `tsd install jquery --save` , and `/// <reference path="../../../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />` I imported UIsearch library like this. Index.html : `<script src="js/uisearch.js"></script> `. Uisearch works normally, but I have an error in terminal

Answer (score 0):

How did you import UISearch? If the library is imported you might want to try:

```
constructor(private UISearch:uisearch){}  

ngAfterViewInit() { 
this.uisearch( document.getElementById( 'sb-search' ) );
```

}

Comment: I installed jquery `tsd install jquery --save`, and `/// <reference path="../../../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />`    I imported UIsearch library like this. Index.html :  `<script src="js/uisearch.js"></script>` . Uisearch works normally, but I have error in terminal